# Screens die even though process is still running

Tags: gnu-screen, openwrt, irssi

I have a problem with running an irssi in a screen session on a tomato usb router setup. Screen reports session as dead, even though the process is still running (both for screen and irssi)

Screen reports this

```
There are screens on:

8387.pts-0.aum  (Dead ???)
5331.pts-1.aum  (Dead ???)
```

And ps

```
5331 roman     1880 S    {screen} SCREEN
5332 roman     1604 S    /bin/sh
5334 roman     9492 S    irssi
```

Is there any way to fix this or at least to attach to a ghost session?